# SSRS Encryption Key backup location

Tags: ssrs, database-internals

I would like to know if there is any metadata table/registry entry where we can find the backup location of SSRS Encryption Key.

I am working on a power shell report to display the Encryption Key backup date. But the challenge is to find out the location so that the script can be generic.

Answer (score -2):

I could see no answer to this since couple of months. I have done my research and have put together in the below link:
http://sqlgeekspro.com/ssrs-encryption-key-backup-information/

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. I know you control the site, but if and when the site disappears, this answer becomes useless. Please post the content here.